# plotting spatial data in ggplot2 with a legend

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am attempting a rather simple plot here, but keep running into trouble.

I have a simple spatial data frame with location name and lat/lon data:

```
   locations <- c("location 1","location 2","location 3")
    lat <- c(35, 35.5, 34)
    lon <- c(-100, -98, -97)
Spatial.locations <- data.frame(locations, lat, lon)
```

Unlike other plotting examples (many of which use mtcars), the actual value being plotted is not numeric, but is a character value. I'm thinking that might be the issue here.

My ultimate goal here is to plot my spatial points on the graph in the same color and with different shapes. What I'm really after though is to create a legend that matches the shapes on the graph so it is easy to identify which station is which. This is an example, but in my actual graph when I plot numerous stations as colored circles with text labels, their text often overrun each other and makes many of them illegible. So this method should be much easier to reference.

I've attempted my solution a couple of different times, but I am unable to generate a legend.

example 1:

```
ggplot(data = Spatial.locations,aes(x=lon, y=lat))+
  geom_point( size = 3)+
  scale_colour_manual(name = "Locations", 
                      labels = c("location 1","location 2","location 3"),
                      values = rep(x="green", times= 3))  +
  scale_shape_manual(name = "Location", 
                     labels = c("location 1","location 2","location 3"),
                     values = c(19,18,17))
```

example 2:

```
ggplot(data = Spatial.locations,aes(x=lon, y=lat), color=locations)+
geom_point(size = 3) +
  labs(color="Locations")
```

Both examples produce output that looks like this with no legend:

[image]

Any help is much appreciated,

Thanks

Comment: Try putting colour inside `aes`....

Comment: That works! Thank you. Still having trouble changing the shape with that solution. It is not reading scale_shape_manual

Comment: also use shape inside aes.

Comment: Yes, that works too. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To obtain the desired output

- drop scale of colour, since it is one value (no need for a legend)
- name the shape vector values (to map shape values to location values)

as in

```
ggplot(Spatial.locations, aes(x = lon, y = lat, shape = locations)) +
  geom_point(colour = "green") +
  scale_shape_manual(
    name = "Location", 
    values = c(`location 1` = 19, `location 2` = 18, `location 3` = 17))
```

which results in

[image]

Comment: This works perfectly. I appreciate your help very much.